# Get list of Departments and number of users per Department in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

I need to create a report from Active Directory. I need to provide list of all Departments and headcount per Department.
But the script didnt work. I have windows server 2019 and powershell 5.1

````
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Departments = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Property Department | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Department -Unique
Write-Host List of Departments and Number of Users per Department ... -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host

foreach ($Department in $Departments) {

Write-Host = Users in $Department =&gt; (Get-ADuser -Filter * -Property Department | Where-Object {$_.Department -like "$Department"}).count -ForegroundColor yellow
}

Write-Host
Write-Host Total Users in Active Directory : (Get-ADUSer -Filter *).count -BackgroundColor red -ForegroundColor white

Write-Host
$greenCheck = @{
Object = [Char]8730
ForegroundColor = 'Green'
NoNewLine = $true
}

Write-Host "Report on Users and Departments ... " -NoNewline
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Write-Host @greenCheck
Write-Host " (Completed)" -ForegroundColor red ```
````

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in one line using [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object)

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties Department | Group-Object -Property Department | Select-Object Count,Name | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```